# Cryptic symbols inside verbatim in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, verbatim

Using `TexStudio` I am getting this weird behaviour where code inside a `verbatim` environment (also happens with `verb` and `lstlisting`) becomes cryptic symbols. However if I copy the symbols and paste them outside the environment or alternatively uncommenting the correct text shows up so my guess is that `TexStudio` is interpreting my input in a weird way.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked which font is used by TeXstudio in this case. It might be missing some symbols, or have the wrong ones.

Comment: Perhaps a configuration issue, where your verbatim environment is shown in some special font? Are you applying a particular theme? Does the issue persist when you switch themes, or disable them?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions that is also what I thought, that Texstudio is misinterpreting the locale of my os but I can't find any reference as to where this stuff is set and where to change it

Comment: I have played around with a few different fonts and encodings and nothing changes :/ Also I created the file seen in the screenshot just before posting (in Linux) so there should not be any interference from other oses/applications

Comment: Could you also copy and paste that text into a code block in your question? Knowing how it appears on this site will tell us for sure what encoding it's using, and allow us to do our own tests with it. Also post the output of `locale` from the terminal.

Comment: Also try going into Options > Configure TeXstudio > Syntax Highlighting and scroll down to "Verbatim" and see if there's a weird setting there.

Comment: OMG thank you when I adjusted syntax highlighting to my liking I must have accidentaly changed the font family for verbatims. I remember that scrolling while the cursor was on the drop down field changed the value, which was kind of annoying

Comment: Also thank you @Ingmar for also pointing the same thing out, I just didn't get what you meant